# How to post raw body data and without ssl certificate verification in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am sending post requests with HTTP package in flutter but it is showing handshaking exception. 
when I use IOClient I solved SSL verification problem but I could not send raw data to server

```
bool trustSelfSigned = true;
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
  ..badCertificateCallback =
  ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => trustSelfSigned);
try {
  IOClient ioClient = new IOClient(httpClient);
  final response = await ioClient.post('${baseUrl}/register/phone', body:
  {
    'phone': '998$phone'
  },
    encoding: Encoding.getByName(name)
  );
  print('response ${response.body}');
}catch(e){
  print(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as:

```
final response = await ioClient.post('${baseUrl}/register/phone', body:
  {
    'phone': '998$phone'
  }
  ,headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader:'application/json'}
  ,encoding: Encoding.getByName(name)
);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Could you give a bit of explanation? It would help OP and future readers :)